# discord.player ffmpeg process 12040 successfully terminated with return code of 1

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

**code:**

```
@client.tree.command()
async def play(interaction: Interaction, url: str):
    global voice
    channel = interaction.user.voice.channel
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, Guild=interaction.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"error")
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"joined")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source = url))
```

**error:**

```
2022-12-10 19:32:48 INFO     discord.voice_client Connecting to voice...
2022-12-10 19:32:48 INFO     discord.voice_client Starting voice handshake... (connection attempt 1)
2022-12-10 19:32:48 INFO     discord.voice_client Voice handshake complete. Endpoint found russia9326.discord.media
2022-12-10 19:32:50 INFO     discord.player ffmpeg process 12040 successfully terminated with return code of 1.
```

initially there was an error that ffmpeg was not found, I downloaded it separately, indicated the path to it and now it's coming out like this